# Camera on iOS in Flutter having different aspect ratio than built-in camera app

Tags: ios, camera, flutter

I am writing an app using Google Flutter.
I need camera functionality and decided to use:
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/camera

This package implements camera functionality across iOS and Android which on paper seems like a great idea.

However I have come across some weird behaviour: When using it in my own code but also when using the example app on the package website the aspect ration is different than the built in camera app on iOS.
The Flutter package camera preview covers about the same in height but does not have as wide a field of view as the iOS app.

That also means that the camera preview does not fill the entire width of the screen as compared to the built in iOS app.

The aspect ratio and focal length of the camera should not depend on flutter or native Swift.

Have anybody come across the same problem and found a solution or explanation.

I would like to have a preview that fills the entire screen and works the same as on native iOS.

Answer (score 0):

The Flutter camera package you are using is calling ObjectiveC code under the hood in order to access iOS API.
From the sources here: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/13c87f828312a5baf87a4fbb51b1f95a63974431/packages/camera/ios/Classes/CameraPlugin.m#L177

you can see that resolutionPreset have multiple values that you can change, it's just the default value used in the package is not the same as on iOS, you can propose a merge request that change the default value if you wish or just set it from you Flutter code.